# Binding inline style opacity value with a watcher property

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I've been trying to bind the opacity of a `div` with the value of a `slider`.

```
<div class="container" v-bind:style="opacity">test content</div>
```

However, I am unable to get the binding working correctly and all is see when checking in developer tools is the `div` gets bound to a certain `[object object]` and not the style itself.

Here's what my watcher looks like:

```
watch:{
opacity: function(oldMessage, newMessage) {
            console.log(this.opacity);
            return {
                '"style"':this.opacity
            }
        },
},...
```

I can see that the values of opacity are coming in on the console correctly. The values range are from 0-1 and look like this.
[image]

I am not sure what's going wrong here in terms on inline binding. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You know we need more than this. What does the opacity property contain? A string, an int, a float, an object , an array, etc.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Added more on how the values look like.

Comment: Can you update the question title please? Saying it is connected with Vue framework.  I was not familiar with Vue and before I checked  google I was thinking what kind of new JS maddnes watchers are. But thanks, I've learned something new.

Answer (score 3):

If `opacity` is a number, you have to use it like:

```
<div class="container" v-bind:style="{opacity: opacity}">test content</div>
```

In `{opacity: opacity}` the first is the CSS property name and the second is the `data` vue property name.

Note: Your usage of the watcher:

```
watch:{
opacity: function(oldMessage, newMessage) {
            console.log(this.opacity);
            return {
                '"style"':this.opacity
            }
        },
},...
```

Makes little sense. Watchers don't return values. You returning that object has no use at all.  Perhaps what you wanted was a computed property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    opacity: 0.5
  },
  computed: {
    containerStyle() {
      return {opacity: this.opacity}
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0.5" step="0.01" v-model="opacity"> {{ opacity }}
  <div class="container" v-bind:style="containerStyle">TEST CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, if I was using `{opacity: opacity}` in the html and returning `this.opacity` from computed property in vue, that'd be the correct way as per first section of your comment?

Comment: If you use `v-bind:style="{opacity: opacity}"` there's no need for a computed property. It will pick up automatically. I just added the computed example because it seemed like something you were trying to do.